# TangoService_connectOnPointCloudAvailable invalid input

Tags: android-ndk, google-project-tango

I have the newest API libraries as of May 2017 and trying to use the `TangoService_connectOnPointCloudAvailable` function in the form

```
// After Binding
TangoErrorType err = TangoConfig_setBool(tango_config_, "config_enable_color_camera", true);

err = TangoService_connectOnImageAvailable(TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR, this, onImageAvailable);

TangoService_connect(this, tango_config_);
```

and I also have my call

```
void onImageAvailable(void *context, TangoCameraId id, const TangoImage *image, const TangoCameraMetadata *metadata) {
  LOGI("TEST: %d", image->height);
}
```

Yet I get an `TANGO_INVALID` value on my `TangoService_connectOnImageAvailable` call even though its exactly as shown in the [reference](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/c/reference/group/camera#tangoservice_connectonimageavailable)

I also have my Camera permission set in the Manifest and cannot figure out why I can't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance the Camera permissions are not being granted automatically **even if** you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />`

The manual way to see with an app already on the device is to run

`adb shell am grant com.my.app.package android.permission.CAMERA`

Other option is to add

```
private static final int MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 100;

if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
{
  requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

somewhere such as in the `onCreate()` in your main activity in the Java side